# Javascript regex include only uppercase A-Z, 0-9 characters but not include 'I' and 'O'

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex should accept only A-Z, 0-9 characters, but not inlcude I, O and should be 10 characters long.

How can I fix this regex I wrote that does not contain I and O.

```
^[A-Z-0-9]{10}$
```

Comment: @palaѕн I mean I & O not digit

Comment: Use `^(?:(?![IO])[A-Z-0-9]){10}$`

Comment: thank you Wiktor this worked @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make ranges that skip I and O:

`^[A-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{10}$`